# Concatenating float columns in Pandas creating a new series without nan

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have a pretty trivial problem, but one that I can't solve. I have a rather long dataset (in the example 1 with 4 columns (A,B,C,D,E).

[image: Dataframe I have]

I need to create a series (or new column) that is the vertical concatenation of other columns in the dataset (A, B and D in the example), ignoring the nan in each of the columns. The result (A+B+D) is a column where only the values present (excluding the nan) are concatenated.

[image: Dataframe I want]

All my numerical values are float. I tried to use pd.concat and other methods, without results.

```
df['A+B+D'] = pd.concat([df['A'].notna(), df['B'].notna(), df['D'].notna()], ignore_index = True, axis = 1)
```

I tried with other methods and some tutorial but I cannot fix the problem.

Comment: please provide a reproducible input

Comment: You second picture is not a valid dataframe. You can't add a new column of different length to a dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming an input DataFrame with a range index (if not: `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`), you can use:

```
s = df[['A', 'B', 'D']].unstack().dropna().reset_index(drop=True).rename('(A+B+D)')

out = df.reindex(s.index).join(s)
```

Output:

```
      A    B    C    D    E  (A+B+D)
0   3.0  NaN  3.0  2.0  5.0      3.0
1   4.0  2.0  1.0  NaN  2.0      4.0
2   NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0      5.0
3   5.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  6.0      7.0
4   7.0  5.0  5.0  4.0  NaN      3.0
5   NaN  3.0  4.0  7.0  3.0      2.0
6   3.0  2.0  5.0  4.0  2.0      3.0
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      4.0
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      5.0
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      3.0
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      2.0
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      2.0
12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      3.0
13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      3.0
14  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      4.0
15  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      7.0
16  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      4.0
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [3.0, 4.0, nan, 5.0, 7.0, nan, 3.0],
                   'B': [nan, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0],
                   'C': [3.0, 1.0, 3.0, nan, 5.0, 4.0, 5.0],
                   'D': [2.0, nan, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0, 4.0],
                   'E': [5.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0, nan, 3.0, 2.0]})
```